# Substituição com sed

Tags: regex, sed

Tenho que fazer substituição em uns arquivos e não estou conseguindo escrever uma expressão que funcione.
Tenho este texto no começo de cada linha:

> NF3-9-16S_S9_1456|M02255:210:000000000-B9K3P:1:1101:14397:18152 1:N:0:9|o:50|m/o:0.720000|MR:n=0;r1=34;r2=2|Q30:p=97;p=100|CO:0|mismatches:36

E ele tem que ficar assim:

> Re1_91910_1456

Somente devo conservar a parte em que está o número "1456", ou seja mudar o começo e apagar tudo o que venha depois do número.

Comment: E da onde vem essa parte `Re1_91910`?

Answer (score 0):

**Resposta**

Use essa regex para capturar o que deseja:

```
NF.*?(\d*)\|.*
```

E essa parte na substituição

```
Re1_91910_$1
```

Resultando em:

```
Re1_91910_1456
```

[Você pode testar o funcionamento dessa regex aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/t7FjVT/1)

**Explicação:**

Essa regex irá capturar todos os dígitos após o `_` e antes do caractere `|` colocando-os no grupo 1 de captura, após isso na parte da regex de substituição, adicionamos a sua cadeia de caractere fixa `Re1_91910_` e o que foi capturado no grupo 1, indicado pelo `$1`, assim você recebe o resultado que você gostaria.